# Express edits URL query to "favicon.ico"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, get

When I send a GET request to my node.js/express web server with a URL after the route, instead of the server recording said URL, it instead stores favicon.ico:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get("/:query", function (req, res) {
    var query = req.params.query;
    console.log(query);
})

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port,  function () {
    console.log('Node.js listening on port ' + port + '...');
});
```

So, when I go to `https://my-domain-url.io/http://www.google.co.uk` what gets printed to the console is: `favicon.ico` instead of `http://google.co.uk`

Does anyone know why this happens and how to prevent it?

(I am currently using  a workaround by using `req.headers.referer` which gives me the full `https://my-domain-url.io/http://www.google.co.uk` which I then manually parse.)

Comment: what do you get in `console.log(query);`

Comment: I would have expected it to print **both**, not *just* the favicon request. (Requests for favicons are entirely expected).

Comment: @NaeemShaikh `console.log(query) === "favicon.ico"`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One way to do this:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get("/*", function (req, res, next) {
    var query = req.params[0];
    console.log(query);
    next(); //you need add next, otherwise your query will hang there
})

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port,  function () {
    console.log('Node.js listening on port ' + port + '...');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This was happening to me...and it was because the HTML was looking for a favicon as a subrequest of the page:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

Basically, the browser requested the "favicon.ico" as a script parameter.  Adding a slash before the resource call solved it for me, like so:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

It's possible, too, that browsers look for the favicon automatically.  [This solution may help](https://gist.github.com/kentbrew/763822) with that.